# Creating two separate joined layers with same geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

I have two layers I want to have the same geometries much like when duplicating layers and joining the layer.

[image]

Essentially this is so I can have a large database within 'Habitats' and a smaller editable and accessible one in 'UKHab Condition Sheet'. Duplicating the Habitats layer and deleting/creating fields does not work as it also updates the parent layer it's duplicated from.

Currently joining the layers creates an attribute in the joined layer but it does not have any geometry nor populates the field.

Aiming for field surveyors to use this in the field so the UKHab Condition Sheet layer would have to auto-generate the Habitats $geometry.

I am using QGIS 3.24.

I am trying to get the same result as the layers within this template http://publications.naturalengland.org.uk/file/4535662744436736

For some reason, the natural England download isn't https
http://publications.naturalengland.org.uk/publication/6049804846366720

Comment: Rather than *Duplicate* you can *Export* the layer to a new file/database. Changes made to the new one won't affect the original.

Comment: I'm using separate geopackages, I'm aiming to have the geometry to behave as if they are duplicated.

Comment: Or you can have one geometry layer and one join table...

Comment: @J.R has the answer, IMO. You can create a table with no geometry but with a key attribute that links every entity in your original data to it.

Comment: How do I go about joining the geometry? In the end I am hoping to have more than 2 layers joined so that they all share the same geometry as there is going to be loads of information. I have a project from http://publications.naturalengland.org.uk/file/4535662744436736 which has the functionality I'm trying to copy.

Comment: At this point I'd have to ask: What is your background on GIS? I'm thinking you need to work with a GIS DB specialist because what you ask kind of hints that you're probably way over your head and SE answers will not be enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe using a virtual layer? Selecting only the geometries from the initial layer you want to use? However, we don'r really know your very task, so its difficult to say what you need.